# PHP Game session not working

Tags: php, session, input

I need a PHP session to store a variable, $CurrentPos, for the location of a player but for whatever reason, it doesn't work. It's probably because I implemented the code wrong, but I just can't figure it out.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'index.php';
$World = simplexml_load_file("gameworld.xml");
$_SESSION["CurrentPos"] = 0 ;
$CurrentPos = $_SESSION["CurrentPos"];
print "<br>";
printplace();
function printplace() {
    GLOBAL $World, $CurrentPos;
    $Room = $World->ROOM[$CurrentPos];
    $Name = $Room->NAME;
    $Desc = wordwrap((string)$Room->DESC);
    print "$Name<br>";
    print str_repeat('-', strlen($Name));
    print "<br>$Desc<br>";
    if ((string)$Room->NORTH != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->NORTH;
        print "North: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$Room->SOUTH != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->SOUTH;
        print "South: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->WEST;
        print "West: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->EAST;
        print "East: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    print "<br>";
}

$input = explode(' ', $input);
print "<br>";
foreach ($input as $command) {
    switch ($command) {
        case 'north':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->NORTH != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->NORTH;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go north!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'south':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->SOUTH != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->SOUTH;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go south!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'west':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go west!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'east':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go east!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'look':
            printplace() ;
            break;
        default:
            print "not a valid command... <br>";
            break;
    }
}
print "<br>Thanks for playing!<br>";
?>
```

For some reason, my session variable doesn't really work - look at [my game](http://urbanadventure.dumpong.tk) to see what I mean (I don't really know how to explain this, I'm a PHP newbie :P ).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're resetting the session to 0 each time this script is called.

Comment: So how would I only set it to 0 the first time?

Comment: You could change $_SESSION["CurrentPos"] = 0 ; to $_SESSION["CurrentPos"] = (isset($_SESSION['CurrentPos']) ? $_SESSION['CurrentPos'] : 0);

Comment: It still doesn't work...? I set it to `$_SESSION["CurrentPos"] = (isset($_SESSION['CurrentPos']) ? $_SESSION['CurrentPos'] : 0);` but it still has the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the session to the current position inside of your switch cases.  After each line (for example):

```
$CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST;
```

Add this line:

```
$_SESSION['CurrentPos'] = $CurrentPos;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.